# Is there a better way to debug layout in AOSP project

Tags: android, android-source

During the android app's development, we can debug layout by layout editor in eclipse ADT plugin or studio. But for AOSP project, since it imported as pure Java project into eclipse. The layout editor can't work. So far, I have to run a build and flash the device after I modified the UI every time. Is there a more effective way to accomplish this?

The environment I'm using is Ubuntu 14.04 and eclipse 4.4

Comment: Do your ordinary Android UI work in the context of a regular SDK application project, even if it's a fake one that merely exists to let you treat the key code as being part of one... though building working incremental versions of your app that way if you can arrange things to make it possible will be a time saver.

Comment: So far, I'm doing the similar things. Set up an application project in android studio, then make a directory in AOSP project tree and create a soft link to the source and res directories of application, then add an Android.mk finally.

Answer (score 2):

I never find solution to design layout in IDE, but you could build only specific module instead of build all and flash the device each time.
Please have a look at `mm` shell function. It will reduce time to build and deploy.

For instance:

```
$ cd your-android-repo
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ cd your-module
$ mm
```

Here some links  to `mm`:

[Building a particular module in the android source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139394/building-a-particular-module-in-the-android-source-code)

[How to build a part of Android AOSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924563/how-to-build-a-part-of-android-aosp)

Comment: Thanks to reply, I know this is kind of solution. Actually I'm doing like this so far. But I still think this is very inefficient. I think there could be some more efficient ways. Just wondering how system app developers to do?

Comment: Thats what they do. And mount/push it to system while the system is in eng mode. If you change the framework layouts then major optimization is inevitable.

Comment: well... I suppose there should be some standalone tools